# wxPython SplitterWindow - Automatically Set Min Pane Size

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm working on a GUI with wxPython. I've been creating and testing all my panels separately and they seem to work well. To test them, I just throw something like this at the end of my files

```
class TestFrame(wx.Frame):
    """Test frame"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(TestFrame, self).__init__(parent, -1, "My Frame",
              size=(-1,-1))
        # Setup main sizer
        self.mainSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        panel = SomethingCoolPanel(self)
        self.mainSizer.Add(panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.mainSizer.SetSizeHints(self)
        self.Center()

class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = TestFrame(None)
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.MainLoop()
```

which turns out well for what I'm doing. I like how self.mainSizer.SetSizeHints(self) sets the window up nicely and sets up a reasonable minimum size.

Can I set up something like this in a splitter window? Right now I'm just setting the minimum pane size and starting position manually. It works at the moment, but there has to be a better way. Also, setting the min pane size applies to both sides of the splitter window. Perhaps I would like the min to be less on the left than it is on the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your panel inside a splitter, of course, why not? The only question is what will be in the other half of the splitter, but I guess you have some idea about this.

To set the initial position, query the best size of your panel and use its vertical or horizontal component (depending on your splitter orientation) to position the sash.

Finally, to set different minimum sizes for the panes, you need to override `wxSplitterWindow::OnSashPositionChanging()` but I'm not sure if doing this is supported from wxPython.

Comment: What is the best way to query the best size of the panel? Also,  I was putting the panels in the splitter window. The thing was, when I tested the panel - it was the test frame's self.mainSizer.SetSizeHints(self) that set the nice minimum size. Calling the same in the panel does not seem to help. I place the panels in the splitter window and they can be resized however

Comment: To get the best size of the panel, call `GetBestSize()` on it. Normally calling `SetSizeHints()` on the main frame should still work as the splitter is supposed to compute its own best size correctly using the best sizes of its sub-windows.

Comment: Thanks. You really know your stuff